# Error while SharePoint Server 2010 setup

Tags: sharepoint-server, setup

[image: Error while SharePoint Server 2010 setup]
Hi,
Excuse me,
This error message appeared while setup . What is the cause of this error,
 and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is the OS on which you are installing SP2010?

Comment: Have you installed all prerequisites?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, you haven't enabled some required roles for the install to be successful.

It's most likely the Application Server Role or Web Server Role.

Follow the linked instructions:

https://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/installing-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-server-2008-r2-which-server-roles-and-features-do-i-need/

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?